# How do I stop the auto importing of imported item in go outside of my project?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have my projects that have many packages which import each other and import outside packages.  When I make a change to one of my low lever packages, and then push it to git it is fine and works in that section.  When I go get it for use in another project that was working perfectly I now get this go get this error:

```
module declares its path as: github.com/xdg-go/scram
    but was required as: github.com/xdg/scram
```

None of my code uses either of those directly.  It looks like it automatically updated some lower external packages and broke things the used to then old import.

How do I either find out the package that is importing the wrong name or stop all auto-updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if this module is for you an indirect dependency, the best fix possible is to update whatever project you import that is directly importing it.

When that is not an option, a solution to this error is to clone the problematic repository locally and use the `replace` directive in your `go.mod` file:

```
module mymodule

replace github.com/xdg/stringprep => ../strprep

go 1.16.2

require (
    github.com/divjotarora/mgo v0.0.0-20190308170442-1d451d2a3149
)
```

where `../strprep` is where the code of the required module exists in your local machine, relative to the `go.mod` file of your project.

The downside of this of course is that you have to replicate this palliative fix wherever you plan to `go get` your modules.

Note also:

- `divjotarora/mgo` is just a random example of a project that imports one of those packages using their old import path.
- I'm using `xdg/stringprep` as an example because I can't find modules that import `xdg/scram` instead, but apparently [it suffers](https://github.com/divjotarora/mgo/blob/v2/auth.go#L38) from the same issue

Beside, you can use:

- `go mod why <package>` to find out why a certain package is listed as a dependency of your project
- `go mod graph` to show the full dependency graph. The output is in `<package> <requirement>` format

Answer (score 2):

The [`go.mod`](https://github.com/xdg-go/scram/blob/master/go.mod) file at github.com/xdg/scram declares itself as `github.com/xdg-go/scram`:

> ```
> module github.com/xdg-go/scram
>
> go 1.11
>
> require (
>   github.com/xdg-go/stringprep v1.0.2
>   golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20210322153248-0c34fe9e7dc2
> )
> ```

The `go.mod` file should be updated to reflect the correct import path.